How To Make My Data Dynamic - Checkout page
I have this custom module which I am using to check if the items in the cart are a promotional/Franke product. If they are then applying an affiliate coupon will have no effect. It works on the original page load and the correct success/error messages display. However when you remove an item from the cart the page does not reload only the cart summary does thus the array still contains the old data. I want to make the data dynamic so that whenever an item is added or removed the array changes and thus the correct popup message will display. Below is my onepage.phtml file which is where I retrieve the data and add it to the array.
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Codazon, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
?>
<?php
$helper = $this->helper(\Codazon\SalesPro\Helper\Data::class); 
// Get all visible items in cart
$quote = $block->getData("view_model")->getQuoteData();
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    $_product = $_item->getProduct();
    $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    $isPromoItem = in_array(206, $categoryIds) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    $containsFranke = strpos($_item->getName(), 'Franke') !== false ? 'Yes' : 'No';

    // echo "<pre>";print_r($_item->debug());
    echo 'ID: '.$_item->getProductId().'<br/>';
    echo 'Name: '.$_item->getName().'<br/>';
    echo 'Sku: '.$_item->getSku().'<br/>';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$_item->getQty().'<br/>';
    echo 'Price: '.$_item->getPrice().'<br/>';
    echo 'Product Type: '.$_item->getProductType().'<br/>';
    echo 'Discount: '.$_item->getDiscountAmount();echo "<br/>";
    echo 'Category IDs: ' .implode(', ', $categoryIds)."<br/>";
    echo 'Promo: '. $isPromoItem.'<br/>'; 
    echo 'Franke: '.$containsFranke.'<br/>';
    echo "<br/>";
}

?>
<div id="checkout" data-bind="scope:'checkout'" class="checkout-container cdz-opc-wrapper">
    <div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif')) ?>"
                 alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Loading...')) ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <?= isset($secureRenderer) ? $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag("position: absolute;", "#checkout-loader img") : ''; ?>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->

    <script>
        var cdzOscConfig = <?= $helper->getCustomOptionsJson() ?>;
        require.config({
            config: {
                mixins: {
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                        'Codazon_SalesPro/js/checkout/view/shipping-mixin': true
                    },
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment': {
                        'Codazon_SalesPro/js/checkout/view/payment-mixin': true
                    },
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address': {
                        'Codazon_SalesPro/js/checkout/view/billing-address-mixin': true
                    },
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default': {
                        'Codazon_SalesPro/js/checkout/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default-mixin': true
                    },
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/sidebar': {
                        'Codazon_SalesPro/js/checkout/view/sidebar-mixin': true
                    },
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/place-order': {
                        'Codazon_SalesPro/js/checkout/model/place-order-mixin': true
                    },
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': {
                        'Codazon_SalesPro/js/checkout/model/checkout-data-resolver-mixin': true
                    }<?php if ((bool)$helper->getConfig('codazon_osc/customization/enable_edit_qty')) : ?>,
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details': {
                        'Codazon_SalesPro/js/checkout/view/summary/item/details-mixin': true
                    }<?php endif ?>
                }
            }
        });
        <?php /* require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/core/app'], function($, app) {
            var opcConfig = <?= $block->getJsLayout() ?>, stepShipping, stepPayment;
            var steps = opcConfig.components.checkout.children.steps.children;
            opcConfig.components.checkout.children.sidebar.config.template = 'Codazon_SalesPro/checkout/sidebar';
            try {
                opcConfig.components.checkout.children.sidebar.children.agreements = {};
                opcConfig.components.checkout.children.sidebar.children.agreements = steps['billing-step'].children.payment.children['payments-list'].children['before-place-order'].children.agreements;
            } catch(err) {
            }
            app(opcConfig, $('#checkout'));
        }); */ ?>
        var cdzOpcConfig = <?= $block->getJsLayout() ?>, stepShipping, stepPayment;
        var steps = cdzOpcConfig.components.checkout.children.steps.children;
        cdzOpcConfig.components.checkout.children.sidebar.config.template = 'Codazon_SalesPro/checkout/sidebar';
        try {
            cdzOpcConfig.components.checkout.children.sidebar.children.agreements = {};
            cdzOpcConfig.components.checkout.children.sidebar.children.agreements = steps['billing-step'].children.payment.children['payments-list'].children['before-place-order'].children.agreements;
        } catch(err) {
        }
        var cdzOpcScript = document.createElement('script');
        cdzOpcScript.type = 'text/x-magento-init';
        cdzOpcScript.textContent = '{"#checkout":{"Magento_Ui/js/core/app":'+ JSON.stringify(cdzOpcConfig) + '}}';
        document.querySelector('body').append(cdzOpcScript)
    </script>
    <?php if (isset($secureRenderer)) : ?>
    <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Codazon_SalesPro::checkout/onepage-secure-renderer.phtml')) ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <script>
        window.checkoutConfig = <?= $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;
        window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
        window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
    </script>
    <script>
        require([
            'mage/url',
            'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
        ], function(url, blockLoader) {
            blockLoader("<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))) ?>");
            return url.setBaseUrl('<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getBaseUrl())) ?>');
        })
    </script>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if (!((bool)$helper->getConfig('codazon_osc/customization/enable_discount_code'))) : ?>
    <style>
    .payment-option.discount-code .payment-option-title, .payment-option.discount-code .payment-option-content{display:none !important;}
    </style>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var promoItems = [];
    var frankeItems = [];

    <?php foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item): ?>
        var isPromoItem = <?php echo in_array(206, $_item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds()) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;
        var containsFranke = <?php echo strpos($_item->getName(), 'Franke') !== false ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;

        promoItems.push(isPromoItem);
        frankeItems.push(containsFranke);
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    window.promoItems = promoItems;
    window.frankeItems = frankeItems;
</script>
</div>

And then I retrieve the data in a different file called apply-coupon.js which is a Mageplaza module so the file is located in a different folder but it still works. The apply-coupon.js file is below

/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_Affiliate
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */

define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Mageplaza_Affiliate/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Mageplaza_Affiliate/js/model/messageList',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/recollect-shipping-rates',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Mageplaza_Affiliate/js/model/coupon'
], function (ko, $, quote, urlManager, errorProcessor, messageContainer, storage, $t, getPaymentInformationAction,
             totals, fullScreenLoader, recollectShippingRates, getTotalsAction, couponModel
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (couponCode, isApplied) {
        var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId(),
            url     = urlManager.getApplyAffiliateCouponUrl(couponCode, quoteId),
            data    = {},
            headers = {};

        fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

        return storage.put(
            url,
            data,
            false,
            null,
            headers
        ).done(function (response) {
            var deferred;

            if (response) {
                deferred = $.Deferred();

                isApplied(true);
                couponModel.isLoading(true);
                totals.isLoading(true);
                recollectShippingRates();
                if ($('body').hasClass('checkout-cart-index')) {
                    getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                } else {
                    getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
                }
                $.when(deferred).done(function () {
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    totals.isLoading(false);
                    couponModel.isLoading(false);

                    // Check for promotional or Franke products before showing message
                    var message = checkProductsForMessages();
                    if (message) {
                        messageContainer.addErrorMessage({'message': message});
                    } else {
                        messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                            'message': $t('Your affiliate coupon was successfully applied.')
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            totals.isLoading(false);
            couponModel.isLoading(false);
            errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
        });
    };

    // Function to check for promo or Franke products and return appropriate message
    function checkProductsForMessages() {
        if (window.promoItems.includes(true)) {
            return $t("Can't apply due to Franke/Promo product. Remove them to apply coupon");
        }

        if (window.frankeItems.includes(true)) {
            return $t("Coupon can't be applied due to a Franke product in your cart.");
        }

        // No promotional or Franke products found, return null
        return null;
    }
    
});

Any advice on how to make the popup message change on the fly(without a page reload) would be greatly appreciated.

The list of items in the cart is available in the customer data pool, and reloaded on each change in the cart.
Here is a sample code that shows how it works :
require([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (customerData) {
    var cart = customerData.get('cart')(); // Fetches cart data pool

    if (cart && cart.items) {
        console.log('Cart Item Count: ' + cart.summary_count);
        console.log('Cart Items: ', cart.items); // Logs the items in the cart
        console.log('Cart Subtotal: ' + cart.subtotal);

        // You can loop through the items and display their details if needed
        cart.items.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log('Item Name: ' + item.product_name);
            console.log('Item Price: ' + item.product_price_value);
            console.log('Item Quantity: ' + item.qty);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Cart is empty.');
    }
});

